# How to pass data from Spreadsheet to client-side using PropertiesService?

Tags: google-apps-script

My functions below work, but I was wondering if this is as per good practices, since I'm not comfortable with the possibility to have properties data clash if it so happens that `PropertiesServices` are used somewhere else to store and pass data on.

**Basic Flow**

1. User ticks a checkbox at the end of a row
2. Event based function sets that row data to script `PropertiesServices`
3. Modal Dialog opens up and runs another function that will get the first `property` in the `PropertiesServices` and clears it all

How can I have it grab the data by its `key` instead without calling the server more than once?

**Function running on edit basis (installable trigger)**

```
function ajustarParcela() {
  const crSht = ss.getSheetByName(crShtName);
  let row = 0;
  let dados = crSht.getRange(6, 1, crSht.getLastRow(), crSht.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const headers = dados[0];

  dados = dados.filter((e, i) => {
    if (e[18] === true) {
      row = i + 6;
      return e;
    }
  });
  if (row < 7) {
    Browser.msgBox('Favor selecionar uma parcela para que possa fazer o seu ajuste.');
    return;
  }
  if (dados.length > 1) {
    Browser.msgBox('Não é possível ajustar mais do uma parcela de cada vez.');
    return;
  }
  dados.unshift(headers);

  //HTML Pop-up
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const htmlWindow = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Pagina_Baixar");
  htmlWindow.dados = JSON.stringify(dados);

  const htmlOutput = htmlWindow.evaluate().setWidth(450).setHeight(570);
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Baixar Parcela");
  crSht.getRange(row, 19).clearContent();
}
```

**Client-Side function**

```
<script>
  const getDadosParcela = () => {
    const dadosParcela = <?!= dados ?>; // In this case, the value of dadosParcela can be used as an array.
    console.log(dadosParcela);
  }

  getDadosParcela(); // This is for testing.
</script>
```

**This is how I connect to the js file**

```
...
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pagina_Baixar_css').getContent(); ?>
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pagina_Baixar_js').getContent(); ?>
</head>
...
```

**Attempt as per answer below**
It generates the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the work process.  Your onEdit `sheetEvents` opens a modal dialog.  At the same time you store the row in Property Servics.  How does the client (the dialog) run `getDadosParcela `?  Why not simply pass the row to the Template before you `evaluate()`?

Comment: How can I do that, @TheWizEd? I guess I got lost digesting the bit I could and can't even see this. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a checkbox after row 6 of column "R" of "Contas a Receber" sheet is checked, you want to retrieve the row value and send the value to the Javascript side, and you want to use the value as a variable of `dadosParcela`.

If my understanding is correct, I think that in your situation, how about using an HTML template? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function sheetEvents(e) {
  const activeSht = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSht.getName() === 'Contas a Receber') {
    const thisRow = e.range.getRow(),
      thisCol = e.range.getColumn(),
      cellVal = e.range.getValue();
    if (thisCol == 18 && thisRow > 6 && cellVal === true) {
      let dadosParcela = activeSht.getRange(thisRow, 1, 1, activeSht.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Pagina_Baixar');
      htmlOutput.dadosParcela = JSON.stringify(dadosParcela);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput.evaluate().setWidth(450).setHeight(700), 'Baixar Parcela');
    }
  }
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<script>
  const getDadosParcela = () => {
    const dadosParcela = <?!= dadosParcela ?>; // In this case, the value of dadosParcela can be used as an array.
    console.log(dadosParcela);
  }

  getDadosParcela(); // This is for testing.
</script>
```

- In this modified script, when a checkbox after row 6 of column "R" of "Contas a Receber" sheet is checked, the row value is retrieved and you can see the row value in the console of the browser at the dialog.
- In this modification, PropertiesService is not required to be used.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

### Added:

From your provided Spreadsheet, I understood the reason for your current issue of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.`. In your current script, `Pagina_Baixar_js.html` is my proposed script. And, `Pagina_Baixar.html` is loaded as the HTML template by `const htmlWindow = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Pagina_Baixar");`. In the HTML of `Pagina_Baixar.html`, `Pagina_Baixar_js.html` is loaded with `<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pagina_Baixar_js').getContent(); ?>`. But, when `evaluate()` is run, `Pagina_Baixar_js` is included as no HTML template. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

##### From:

```js
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const htmlWindow = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Pagina_Baixar");
htmlWindow.dados = JSON.stringify(dados);

const htmlOutput = htmlWindow.evaluate().setWidth(450).setHeight(570);
ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Baixar Parcela");
crSht.getRange(row, 19).clearContent();
```

##### To:

```js
const js = 'Pagina_Baixar_js';
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const html2 = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(js);
html2.dados = JSON.stringify(dados);
const html2Content = html2.evaluate().getContent();
const htmlWindow = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Pagina_Baixar");
htmlWindow[js] = html2Content;
const htmlOutput = htmlWindow.evaluate().setWidth(450).setHeight(570);
ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Baixar Parcela");
crSht.getRange(row, 19).clearContent();
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

`Pagina_Baixar_js` is not required to be modified. And, please modify `Pagina_Baixar.html` as follows.

##### From:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pagina_Baixar_js').getContent(); ?>
```

##### To:

```
<?!= Pagina_Baixar_js ?>
```

- By this modification, `Pagina_Baixar_js` reflected the value of `JSON.stringify(dados)` is put to `Pagina_Baixar`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gives me the following error in the browser's console, though: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. I've updated my question with the client-side function.

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. About `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. I've updated my question with the client-side function.`, I'm worried that your script is different from your showing script in your question. How about this? Because when I tested the scripts in my answer, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your actual scripts if your showing script was different from your tested script?

Comment: @onit For example, can you provide your sample Spraedsheet including your current script for replicating `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. I've updated my question with the client-side function.`?

Comment: I've updated the question with the actual scripts. Appreciate your help so much!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. From your reply, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. I've updated my question with the client-side function.`. When I tested your showing script, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill, again. But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly replicating your current issue, can you provide your sample Spraedsheet including your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: [Here it is:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dnq5ghug_ldZLjIVBruBV666nJ6MghLioTuHsCaxDFQ/edit?usp=sharing). Thanks a million!

Comment: @onit Thank you for providing your project. From your provided project, I understood the filenames of each HTML. By this, I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @onit By the way, now, I noticed that my updated answer might be an answer to your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75709038 If my understanding is correct, how about removing it, because of the duplicate question? But, if I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! It would have taken me ages to solve it... Thank you! The other question has been removed.

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. and your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.